# laravel's session issue: can't retrieve data from session when router in api.php

Tags: php, laravel, session

**I am trying to pass data by session.**

There are two funtion in my controller:

```
public function setEdit(Request $request){
    session(['estateId' => $request->estateId]);
    return response()->json(['message' => 'success' ]);
}

public function getEdit(){
    return response()->json(['base'=> session('estateId')]);
}
```

when I call getEdit() method at **web.php** , it will retrieve estateId correctly.
web.php:

```
Route::post('/setEdit', 'API\EstateController@setEdit');
Route::get('/getEdit', 'API\EstateController@getEdit');
```

However, if I call getEdit() method at **api.php**, it won't get estateId.
api.php

```
Route::post('/setEdit', 'API\EstateController@setEdit');
Route::get('/getEdit', 'API\EstateController@getEdit');
```

I am pretty sure I am doing right on front-end. 
And I didn't forget to change URL when I move router from web.php to api.php.

**So why can't I use session when router is in api.php**

---

ok, now I know that using session to pass data between each page, seems be a bad idea.

This is my front-end, I trying to pass data and redirect.

```
let apiUrl = '../api/estate/setEdit';
let config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}
};
let postItem = {'estateId':estateId};
axios.post(apiUrl, postItem ,config).then(response => {
    location.replace('edit-estate');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I figure out I can put estate_id as parameters in URL ( **eg. location.replace('edit-estate?estate_id=15');** )

There is my new question:

**1. How to put token in header?


2. If I want to pass a json how to do it?**

Comment: That's because the routes defined in api file are intended to be stateless which means you can't use sessions in your requests but you can use headers and tokens

Comment: @AmrAly  thanks for reply,  I fix my code at bottom please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you should not use sessions in api because larval won't initiate sessions in case of api. look at kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\InitiateApp::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

You better use post parameters and token based authentication for api services instead of session, but you may use web middle ware instead of api, for both API & Web requests (not recommended).

Comment: thanks for reply, I fix my code at bottom please have a look.

Comment: @jimmy you better ask your new question in a separate question because it is not related to the subject.Anyway, i am not familiar with iOS programming but i know you can send both token & data (as well as JSON encoded data) using POST protocol.